# PowerShell - Azure Site Recovery - Failover

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-site-recovery, powershell-az-module

If we want to failover Replicated VM in Azure using Azure Site Recovery.

Can we replicate VMs to a different subscription ?

Eg. When configuring ASR - Disaster recovery I gave subscription name 'ABC' for replication to happen.
At the time of failover I want VM to failover to 'PQR' subscription and not 'ABC' where replication was happening till now

Have any one tried this with PowerShell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DBA Admin The Subscription cannot be changed once selected. However, Azure site recovery does offer "[Cross-subscription disaster recovery for Azure virtual machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/cross-subscription-dr/)"